# UIButton state change

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton

I have created a button using code shown below -

```
UIImage *kalenderImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"start_icon_calendar_u.png"];
UIImageView *kalenderImageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,  kalenderImage.size.width/2, kalenderImage.size.height/2)] autorelease];
[kalenderImageView setImage:kalenderImage];
UILabel* kalendarLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake (0, kalenderImage.size.height/2-15, kalenderImage.size.width/2, kalenderImage.size.height/2)] autorelease];
kalendarLabel.text = @"Kalender";   
[kalenderButton addSubview:kalenderImageView];
[kalenderButton addSubview:kalendarLabel];
[kalenderButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showCalendar:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

I need to change the image of button for `UIControlStateHighlighted` state. How can i do this ?
I dont want to use

```
KalenderButton setBackgroundImage:@"" forState:] 
[KalenderButton setImage:@"" forState]
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple. Look at the following code. It checks the file is locked and changes the image of the button accordingly. You can edit the code according to your necessity.

```
if (fileLocked) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"icon-lock.png"]];
        [lockButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"icon-unlock.png"]];
        [lockButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
```

It works.